# Omit one column in Google Chart

Tags: python, google-visualization

As the title says, I want to display a Google Chart omitting one column of my data table. My table has the following structure:

```
['2016-01-05 12:45:05', 1.187, 20.375, 45.375],
['2016-01-05 13:00:04', 1.687, 21.437, 43.937],
['2016-01-05 13:15:04', 2.062, 22.062, 43.25],
```

There are four columns, but I only want to display the first, third and fourth column in my chart.

My Google Chart snippet looks like this:

```
def print_graph_script(table):

# google chart snippet
chart_code="""
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3'], %s ]);

        var options = {
            animation:{"startup": true, duration: 1500, easing: 'out', },
            title: 'Temperature',
            showAxisLines:true,
            hAxis: {
                title: '',
                slantedText:true,
                slantedTextAngle:90,
                textStyle: {fontSize: '12'}
                },
            vAxis: {
                title: '',
                textStyle: {fontSize: '12'}
                },
            series: {
                0: { color: '#333333' },
                1: { color: '#75baff' },
                2: { color: '#eba314' },
                }
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>"""

print chart_code % (table)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) -- then use `hideColumns`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But this method throws an error. Maybe I´m doing something wrong. Here is what I did: `var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0,2,3]);` but that gives me `Invalid column index 3. Should be an integer in the range [0-2].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, buy using two views seems to work.
I did receive the same error as in the comment using just one view.
Here, I create view 1, hide the column, then create view 2 from view 1.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'],
        ['2016-01-05 12:45:05', 1.187, 20.375, 45.375],
        ['2016-01-05 13:00:04', 1.687, 21.437, 43.937],
        ['2016-01-05 13:15:04', 2.062, 22.062, 43.25],
    ]);

    var dataView1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    dataView1.hideColumns([1]);
    var dataView2 = new google.visualization.DataView(dataView1);

    var options = {
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'out'
        },
        title: 'Temperature',
        showAxisLines: true,
        hAxis: {
            title: '',
            slantedText:true,
            slantedTextAngle:90,
            textStyle: {fontSize: '12'}
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: '',
            textStyle: {fontSize: '12'}
        },
        series: {
            0: { color: '#333333' },
            1: { color: '#75baff' },
            2: { color: '#eba314' },
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataView2, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: That is working fine, just I expected it to be. Kind of strange that you have to create two views to get the result, but it works out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why not just filter the table like

```
table_filtered = [ [row[0], row[2], row[3]] for row in table]
```

and pass `table_filtered` to the print

Comment: Maybe the data is still needed in the browser for some other purpose? I've had to hide data in a chart but still required it for some other function.